# iOS/Cordova: How to create shortcut on home screen, and call a Cordova App's function on tap?

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap, homescreen, shortcut

Is it possible to create a shortcut on the home screen (like **share to home screen** from safari) from my Cordova application on iOS?

The idea is, when the user taps on this shortcut, to call a function of my Cordova application (with data or a simple URL).

I've found a working example for Android:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-shortcuts-android

Comment: What do you exactly mean with "with data, or a simple URL" ?

Comment: With options for function like   do_ex_func(id);

Comment: trind to find same thing. Not sure if js works here, i think only java. Did you found something untill now?

Comment: Nope no solution